# How to change position of Tab Navigation?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I currently have Tab Based app and the tabs are on bottom. Is there any way to put them up?

[image: Visual explanation in picture]

Comment: Have you tried tab layout

Comment: Bottom navigation is also a view so u can keep it anywhere you want in your XML

Comment: Can I use 2 different navigations? React-native-navigation and react-native-tab-view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Add Tabs To Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral#tabs)**

> To create tabs using ActionBar, you need to enable
> NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS, then create several instances of ActionBar.Tab
> and supply an implementation of the ActionBar.TabListener interface
> for each one. For example, in your activity's onCreate() method, you
> can use code similar to this:
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>      final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
>     // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
>     actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
>     
>     // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
>     ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
>         public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
>                 // show the given tab
>         }
>     
>         public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
>                 // hide the given tab
>         }
>     
>         public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
>                 // probably ignore this event
>         }
>     };
>     
>     // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
>     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
>         actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab " + (i + 1)).setTabListener(tabListener));
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> How you handle the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks to change tabs
> depends on how you've constructed your content. But if you're using
> fragments for each tab with ViewPager as shown above, the following
> section shows how to switch between pages when the user selects a tab
> and also update the selected tab when the user swipes between pages.

From [Docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20180529230349/https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral).